# PHP Function : how do send value to html

Tags: php, mysql

i have this function for check news files from MySQL database:

```
function check_Files($id){

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file){
            $url = $file['url'];
        return TRUE;
        }

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

HTML :

```
if(check_Files($id) == TRUE){

echo $url;

}
```

But I see this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: url in ......
```

How do can I back/send `$url` from function to html ?!

Comment: What kind of database library is behind your `sqlaccess` class? Maybe they return values as properties: `$file->url`

Comment: You are using loop to get the urls and it might be possible to have multiple urls ?

Comment: Your code could be vulnerable to SQL injection. Use PDO if possible!

Comment: @tangrs: this is `PDO` with customize Code ;)

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't look like you're using any of the parameter binding code in the PDO library... Well, as long as `$id` and `FILES` is properly sanitised, I guess it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
return TRUE;
```

in your `check_Files` function do:

```
return $url;
```

And use it in following way:

```
if (($url = check_Files($id)) !== false){

    echo $url;

}
```

Or to pass an array of urls from database:

```
function check_Files($id){

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        $urls = array();
        foreach($files as $file){
            $urls[] = $file['url'];
        }
        return $urls;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}

if (($urls = check_Files($id)) !== false){

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo $url;
    }

}
```

The test can be simplified to:

```
if ($urls = check_Files($id)){}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about [variable scope](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Inside the function, $url exists. Outside the function, it isn't around anymore. Your best bet is to return the URL instead of true/false:

```
function check_Files($id){

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file){
            $url = $file['url'];
        return $url;
        }

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Then outside in your code, you can call it like so:

```
$link=check_Files($id);
echo $link;
```

Or even simply

```
echo check_Files($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_Files($id){

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file){
            $url = $file['url'];
        return $url;
        }

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

and in html

```
if (($url = check_Files($id)) != false){

    echo $url;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160124/php-function-how-do-send-value-to-html#comment37286254_24160191

Answer (score 0):

Is the function defined in the same file that is is being called ?? Because the error seems to be that you are trying to output a variable that has not be defined. 
A better approach would be

```
function check_Files($id){

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file){
            $url = $file['url'];
        return $url
        }

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}

if(check_Files($id) != FALSE){

echo check_Files($id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make $url global inside the function and define $url above the function then only you can get the $url;

```
$url="";

function check_Files($id){
    global $url;

    $files = sqlaccess::fetch("SELECT url FROM ".FILES." WHERE news_id=".$id." AND type = 'video' "); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach($files as $file){
            $url = $file['url'];
        return TRUE;
        }

    } else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}

if(check_Files($id) == TRUE){
    echo $url;
}
```

Check yourself and enjoy!